# Sequence for CSS multi column fluid design with max-width (resize in particular order)

Tags: html, css

There are many tutorials out there teaching people how to setup three columns fluid design with min-width, max-width, etc.  E.g. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/

My problem here is that, whenever I try to resize the browser window, right column get resized first, when it reaches the min-width, center column get resized, etc. Anyone has an idea? Preferably without using Javascript or any CSS hacks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use percentage based widths to have fluid grid, and optionally set min widths on your columns (just give your container a min-width of the sum of its children to prevent cols breaking):

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div>col 1</div>
    <div>col 2</div>
    <div>col 3</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

css:

```
.wrap {
   width:100%;    
   min-width:500px;
}
.wrap > div { 
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
}

.wrap > div:nth-child(1){ 
    background : #FCC;
   width:20%;
    min-width:100px
}
.wrap > div:nth-child(2){ 
    background : #CFC;
    width:60%;
    min-width:300px
}.wrap > div:nth-child(3){ 
    background : #CCF;
   width:20%;
    min-width:100px
}
```

Comment: Yes I did try this, however when you resize, all three columns resized together given the fact that they are all percentage based

Comment: Oh, your question was worded like the problem was your right column resized first. It will be hard to avoid using JS for this, if you're not too worried about cross browser, you could maybe use the flex box model? Quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UHPcc/6/